# Print index and value of largest shape in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe and want the index and value of the largest shape in a particular column. The column itself consists of numpy arrays with varying shapes, (99, 13) is most common but also larger and smaller shapes are present. I already put all shapes in a column by means of `merged_test['shapes'] = [x.shape for x in merged_test.MEL.values]` but cannot use standard methods to find the largest shape since shapes are tuples. Any suggestions?

Comment: How you do define `largest shape`? Is it the shape[0] or the sum or the multiplication?

Answer (score 0):

You could do it by getting the size and index of all your elements using np.product and enumerate, putting these in a dataframe, then sorting descending by size and taking the top row:

```
#One-liner
pd.DataFrame([(i, np.product(x.shape)) for i, x in enumerate(merged_test.MEL.values)], columns=['index','size']).sort('size', ascending=False).iloc[0]

#Or splitting it out to see each step
inds_and_sizes = [(i, np.product(x.shape)) for i, x in enumerate(merged_test.MEL.values)]
df = pd.DataFrame(inds_and_sizes, columns=['index','size'])
df_sorted = df.sort('size', ascending=False)
biggest = df_sorted.iloc[0]
```